# How can I match a line containing only a single instance of a pattern with grep?

Tags: regex, grep

Given a text file such as this, say `phrases.txt` with contents:

```
Hahahahahasdhfjshfjshdhfjhdf
Hahahaha!
jdsahjhshfjhfHahahaha!dhsjfhajhfjhf
Hahaha!Hahaha!
dfhjfsf
sdfjsjf Hahaha! djfhjsdfh
Ha! hdfshdfs
Ha! Ha! Ha!
```

What would be an appropriate `grep` command in bash that would output only the lines that contain only a single occurrence of laughter, where laughter is defined as a string
of the form `Hahahahaha!` with arbitrarily many `ha`s. The first `H` is always capital and the other ones are not, and the string must end in `!`. In my example, the egrep command should output:

```
Hahahaha!
jdsahjhshfjhfHahahaha!dhsjfhajhfjhf
sdfjsjf Hahaha! djfhjsdfh
Ha! hdfshdfs
```

A command I came up with was:

```
egrep "(Ha(ha)*\!){1}" phrases.txt
```

The issue with my command is that it does not only output the lines with only a single occurrence of laughter. With my command, line 4 (`Hahaha!Hahaha!`) and line 8 (`Ha! Ha! Ha!`) also get printed which is not what I want.

Is there a nice way to do this with only grep?

Comment: Consider a pipeline of two greps. The first one looks for laughter and the second one excludes (i.e., grep -v) lines having laughter.*laughter.

Comment: Going forward, try to make your title *specific to the individual question*; it should not just describe the general topic, but the question itself, sufficient that someone else should be able to tell if an answer to your question is likely to answer their question as well without needing to click through and read the body. (I've edited towards that end).

Comment: @JeffHolt Thank you for your suggestion! I was thinking of something similar.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I see. I will try to keep that in mind next time, thanks for letting me know!

Comment: you can also use `awk -F'Ha(ha)*!' 'NF==2'` which will split lines based on the given regex and print lines having two fields, meaning only one matching occurrence

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you are okay with pipes then

```
egrep '(Ha(ha)*!)' yourfile.txt | egrep -v '(Ha(ha)*!).*(Ha(ha)*!)'
```

first filter for at least one laugh, then filter out the ones that have more than one laugh.

Note: `{1}` only repeats the previous chunk, it doesn't check the rest of the string to insist that there is only one. So `a{1}` and `a` are actually the same.

Comment: This is exactly what I have just tried and it worked! Thanks for your suggestion and feedback about the repetition operator {1}! I misinterpreted how {1} works precisely.

Answer (score 0):

If you use a GNU `grep` or `pcregrep` that support PCRE regex, you may use

```
grep -P '^(?!(?:.*Ha(ha)*!){2}).*Ha(ha)*!'
```

The pattern is:

```
^(?!(?:.*YOUR_PATTERN_HERE){2}).*YOUR_PATTERN_HERE
```

where `YOUR_PATTERN_HERE` stands for your pattern you want to occur only once in the string.

**Details**

- `^` - start of a strig
- `(?!(?:.*YOUR_PATTERN_HERE){2})` - a negative lookahead that fails the match, immediately to the right of the current location (here, the start of string), there are two consecutive occurrences of

  - `.*` -  any 0+ chars other than line break chars
  - `YOUR_PATTERN_HERE` - your required pattern
- `.*` - any 0+ chars other than line break chars
- `YOUR_PATTERN_HERE` - your required pattern.

See the [online demo](https://rextester.com/JVKP43946):

```
s="Hahahahahasdhfjshfjshdhfjhdf
Hahahaha!
jdsahjhshfjhfHahahaha!dhsjfhajhfjhf
Hahaha!Hahaha!
dfhjfsf
sdfjsjf Hahaha! djfhjsdfh
Ha! hdfshdfs
Ha! Ha! Ha!"
echo "$s" | grep -P '^(?!(?:.*Ha(ha)*!){2}).*Ha(ha)*!'
```

Output:

```
Hahahaha!
jdsahjhshfjhfHahahaha!dhsjfhajhfjhf
sdfjsjf Hahaha! djfhjsdfh
Ha! hdfshdfs
```